# Restore FragmentManager backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation, fragmentmanager, fragment-backstack

I have different layouts for portrait and landscape. My UI uses fragments stacked in back stack. On device rotation I need to set a different layout for landscape/portrait and restore the stack of fragments(note that each fragment also has different layouts for portrait and landscape). I need to preserve data in EditTexts, selections etc.
To make it easier imagine that in portrait I have the following fragments in my backstack FragmentA->FragmentB->FragmentC. Then I rotate the device, a different layout loads for my activity and I need to restore FragmentA->FragmentB->FragmentC again but with their views for landscape. How should I proceed?

Comment: When the fragments are restored, `onCreateView()` is called again which inflates the correct layout for that orientation. In other words, it should Just Work.  I suggest that you try it out and when you find a specific problem restoring your fragments, update this question with the exact details of the problem you are having.

Comment: It will not 'just work' in this case because in onCreate() of my activity I create a new layout and set it via setContentView() i.e. the layout frame in which these fragments are created is changed as well which wipes the backstack.

Comment: The way I've solved that problem is to check if `savedInstanceState` is null; if it isn't, I don't do the initial fragment transaction.  Then the fragments are restored from the saved state.

Comment: will this work if I set the content view of the activity? I have to set that view too on orientation change because the layouts are different :( I think this will wipe the back stack as all of the fragments 'live' within the root layout.

Comment: It should work, provided that you are using the same id for the fragment container in your different layouts.  It seems like it should clear saved state because you're thinking about the view tree, but a fragment is not a view, and the `FragmentManager` is responsible for saving/restoring state.  For my app, I find if I set the content view but don't run any fragment transactions, my fragments all restore from their last state.